# MySQL - Error in fetching records

Tags: mysql

I have THREE tables.

```
Table : products  
column : id, productname

Table :attribute_master 
column : id, attributename

Table : assignedproductfilter 
column :  id, productid (FK products), filterid (FK attribute_master)
```

table `assignedproductfilter` may contain same `productid` with multiple `filterid`.

Example :

```
| id | productid | filterid |
|----|-----------|----------|
| 1  | 105       | 56       |
| 2  | 105       | 50       |
| 3  | 105       | 34       |
| 4  | 200       | 56       |
| 5  | 201       | 22       |
```

Now, suppose I want to get all those products where `filterid` is 56, 50 and 34. All these three `filter id` should be assigned to `products`.

How to write query for this in mysql?

Comment: Have you tried something? What problems have you faced? At SO, people get help after they try and share their difficulties, not when they ask "solve this problem for me"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.* FROM products AS p
INNER JOIN WITH assignedproductfilter AS af ON af.productid = p.id
WHERE af.filterid IN (56, 50, 34)
```

Please, next time before asking try to make own attempt.

And use something like [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or just include your schema definition SQL.